# Android - Kotlin : Sending a non empty jsonObject but receiving an empty one

Tags: php, android, json, kotlin

I am sending a json from a php file to receive via a kotlin code in android studio. 
I write the json, before send it, to a file "test.txt" and the contents of this file after the execution is :

**test.txt**

```
{"resultarray":{"result":115}}
```

The part of the **php** file is the following

```
$response = array('result' => 115);     
$response1 = array('resultarray' => $response);
$encoded = json_encode($response1);
file_put_contents("test.txt",$encoded);
header('Content-type: application/json');
exit($encoded);
```

The **Post** class I am using is the following :

```
class Post {

@SerializedName("resultarray")
@Expose
public var resultarray: JSONObject? = null


override fun toString(): String {
   if (resultarray == null )
    {
        return " 'resultarray' is null"

    }else {
        val entries = resultarray?.keys() 
        if (entries == null) {
            return " 'entries' is null"
        }else {
            var tostr = "start"
            for (entry in entries) {
                var whatweget  = resultarray?.get(entry)
                if(whatweget != null) {
                    tostr += " " + whatweget
                }
            }
            return tostr + "end"
        }
    }
```

When the above segment of code is executed the resulted string is

```
startend
```

I don't know how to take the 'result' field which is equivalent to understand how to take a jsonobject from inside a jsonobject. 
Also the **resultarray** is equal with "{}". So the problem maybe is with the annotation of the **resultarray**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830767/android-parse-jsonobjects-inside-jsonobject but it was not helpfull

Comment: put breakpoint to line `val entries = resultarray?.keys() ` and check what gets to `entries`

Comment: resultarray is empty this is what I get : {} . 
So  the problem is what ?

Comment: can you check the response of your server what you are actually getting? or if you read from the file, error could be in reading from the file. you need to put breakpoints one step before you got empty array and try to find where the issue happens. also it is better to use `if (resultarray.isNotEmpty())` then ` if (resultarray == null )` because it also checks if array is not empty

Comment: What I send from the server i is what I write to the "test.txt" , as you see I return it.  The array is empty from the start of the code that can access the post object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix of the problem was to declare the **resultarray** as **JSONElement** (as you can see below).

```
class Post {
@SerializedName("resultarray")
@Expose
public var resultarray: JsonElement? = null

    override fun toString(): String {
        return ""+resultarray;
    }
}
```

I took as output when toString() was called:

```
{"result":115}
```